# MySQL query the latest duplicate

Tags: mysql, duplicates

EDIT:

I'm trying to do a MySQL query which will give me the latest entry for duplicates together with those without any duplicates.

This is what my table look like:

mentor table:

```
   mentor_id    applicant_id    mentor_count    mento_email mentor_name mentor_pass
    193     92      1       test@yahoo.com  test        1234
    194     92      2       table@yahoo.com table       4567
    195     92      3       lamp@yahoo.com  lamp        7890
    196     92      1       test@yahoo.com  test        1234
    197     92      2       table@yahoo.com table       4567
    198     92      3       lamp@yahoo.com  lamp        7890
```

mf table:

```
  mf_id     mentor_id   dept        contact     orgname     yrs     length      sak social  char    goal    resp    emomat  res others  impact  evaluation
43      193     math dept   9111111     etc     1       1       e   e   e   e   e   e   e   e   e   good
114     196     math dept   9111111     etc     1       1       e   e   e   e   e   e   e   e   e   good
193     197     sci dept    9222222     org     2       2       n   n   n   n   n   n   n   n   n   medium
194     194     sci dept    9222222     org     2       2       n   n   n   n   n   n   n   n   n   medium
220     195     eng dept    9333333     hello       3       3       q   q   q   q   q   q   q   q   q   bad
```

I tried using this query:

```
 SELECT *
FROM mentor m1
LEFT JOIN (

SELECT mentor_name, max( mentor_id ) AS maxid
FROM mentor m
GROUP BY m.mentor_id
)m2 ON m1.mentor_name = m2.mentor_name
AND m1.mentor_id < m2.maxid
LEFT JOIN mf ON m1.mentor_id = mf.mentor_id
WHERE m1.applicant_id =833
AND m2.maxid IS NULL
ORDER BY m1.mentor_id ASC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

but this is what happens:

```
mentor_id   applicant_id    mentor_count    mentor_email    mentor_name mentor_pass mentor_name maxid   mf_id   mentor_id   dept    contact orgname yrs length  sak social  char    goal    resp    emomat  res others  spirit  concept comm    impact  evaluation
/*there is data here but the column for mentor_name onwards is null*/
```

How can I make it so that the columns for mentor_name onwards is not null, but still displays the latest duplicates as well as those without any duplicates?

Comment: please show your table structure and some example data

Comment: How are you determining its a duplicate? is it purely for applicant_id=92? so any other applicant_id's of 92 are all his?

Comment: there is only one applicant_id 92

Answer (score 0):

try

```
select * from mentor 
where mentor_id in 
(
      SELECT max(mentor_id) from mf 
      where applicant_id = 92 
      group by mentor_id
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to add `mentor.application_id = mf.application_id` to the `JOIN` condition

```
select * 
from mentor 
inner join
(
    SELECT *, max(mentor_id) as maxid 
    from mf 
    group by mentor_id
) mf on mentor.mentor_id = mf.maxid AND mentor.application_id = mf.application_id
where applicant_id = 92
```

Typically you will need an extra condition to get the duplicates. `WHERE applicant_id = 92` won't be a duplicate unless there were others with the same `applicant_id` in the same table.